# MVC and Generic Edit Functionality using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

Is it possible to create a js object and a few functions in a razor partial that can be shared among derived partials?

I want to do something like....

```
_BasePartial
{
   define something using js
}

...

_DerivedPartial:_BasePartial
{
   update something js
   cause _base to act on something js
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS defined both in the BasePartial and DerivedPartial views end up executing on the same page context, so there should be no problem with your use case. For example:

```
_BasePartial:
    var something = { someVar: 2 };

    function doSomething() {
        printSomething(); //Defined on the derived view
    }

_DerivedPartial :
    function updateSomething() {
        something.someVar = 4;

        doSomething(); //Defined on the base view, should output "4" on the console
    }

    function printSomething() {
        console.log(something.someVar);
    }

SomewhereInThePage :
    //Just make sure that the BasePartial JS was executed when calling the 
    // function defined on the derived view
    updateSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks! I am looking at ways to ensure that only one copy of script is on page. In the case when there may be one or many instances of derived views on page at any time.

Comment: ...sorry Hi, when I set $(document).ready(function (){var something.someVar=4; and call doSeomthing();} in the derived class I continue to get 2 for the value of someVar. The derived script is below the base. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 'var something.someVar = 4;' is not a valid JS statement. Regardless, you shouldn't use 'var' if you want to access the global scope variable, as using 'var' would simply declarer a local variable with the same name, effectively hidding the global one within it's scope.